# App auto closes after selecting list view item

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie in android programming, and i am not sure what is wrong with the code. Please have a look and suggest some opinions or fixes! Thank you in advance!

**ExerciseFragment:**

```
public class ExerciseFragment<MainActivity> extends Fragment {
// Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String TITLE = "title";
    static String DIFFICULTY = "difficulty";
    static String CATEGORY = "category";
    static String IMAGE = "image";
    static String DESCRIPTION ="description";

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exercise, container, false);
 // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute(); 
        return rootView;    
    }// DownloadJSON AsyncTask

    public class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Exercise Tips!");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progress dialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/MZZHIfy");

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("exercisecategory");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrieve JSON Objects
                map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));
                map.put("difficulty", jsonobject.getString("difficulty"));
                map.put("category", jsonobject.getString("category"));
                map.put("description", jsonobject.getString("description"));
                map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the listview in fragment_exercise.xml
        listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), arraylist);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**ListViewAdapter:**

```
@SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ListViewAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView title;
    TextView difficulty;
    TextView category;
    TextView description;
    ImageView image;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exe_list, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    resultp = data.get(position);

    // Locate the TextViews in exe_list.xml
    title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    difficulty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.difficulty);
    category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
    description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);

    // Locate the ImageView in exe_list.xml
    image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
    title.setText(resultp.get(ExerciseFragment.TITLE));
    difficulty.setText(resultp.get(ExerciseFragment.DIFFICULTY));
    category.setText(resultp.get(ExerciseFragment.CATEGORY));
    description.setText(resultp.get(ExerciseFragment.DESCRIPTION));

    // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
    // Passes images URL into ImageLoader.class
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(ExerciseFragment.IMAGE), image);
    Log.e("TEST","message here1");

    // Capture ListView item click
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.e("TEST","message here2");
            // Get the position
            resultp = data.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
            Log.e("TEST","message here3");
            // Pass all data title
            intent.putExtra("title", resultp.get(ExerciseFragment.TITLE));
            Log.e("TEST","message here4");
            // Pass all data difficulty
            intent.putExtra("difficulty", resultp.get(ExerciseFragment.DIFFICULTY));
            Log.e("TEST","message here5");
            // Pass all data category
            intent.putExtra("category",resultp.get(ExerciseFragment.CATEGORY));
            Log.e("TEST","message here6");
            // Pass all data description
            intent.putExtra("description", resultp.get(ExerciseFragment.DESCRIPTION));
            Log.e("TEST","message here7");
            // Pass all data image
            intent.putExtra("image", resultp.get(ExerciseFragment.IMAGE));
            Log.e("TEST","message here8");
            // Start SingleItemView Class
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    return itemView;
}
```

**SingleItemView:**

```
public class SingleItemView extends Activity {
// Declare Variables
String title;
String difficulty;
String category;
String description;
String image;
String position;
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from exe_single.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.exe_single);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Get the result of title
    title = i.getStringExtra("title");
    // Get the result of difficulty
    difficulty = i.getStringExtra("difficulty");
    // Get the result of category
    category = i.getStringExtra("category");
    // Get the result of description
    description = i.getStringExtra("description");
    // Get the result of image
    image = i.getStringExtra("image");

    // Locate the TextViews in exe_single.xml
    TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView txtdifficulty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.difficulty);
    TextView txtcategory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.category);
    TextView txtdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);

    // Locate the ImageView in exe_single.xml
    ImageView imgimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    // Set results to the TextViews
    txttitle.setText(title);
    txtdifficulty.setText(difficulty);
    txtcategory.setText(category);
    txtdescription.setText(description);

    // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
    // Passes image images URL into ImageLoader.class
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(image, imgimage);
}
```

Logcat:

```
05-11 14:30:26.400: I/PGA(4771): Attempting to create new SOCKET connectionn pid = 4771, tid = 4771
05-11 14:30:26.410: I/PGA(4771): New SOCKET connection: com.fwong.eatright (pid 4771, tid 4771)
05-11 14:30:31.620: I/MemoryCache(4771): MemoryCache will use up to 48.0MB
05-11 14:30:31.640: D/dalvikvm(4771): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 397K, 13% free 3511K/4004K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
05-11 14:30:31.650: E/TEST(4771): message here1
05-11 14:30:31.670: E/TEST(4771): message here1
05-11 14:30:31.680: E/TEST(4771): message here1
05-11 14:30:31.680: I/MemoryCache(4771): cache size=50784 length=1
05-11 14:30:31.820: I/MemoryCache(4771): cache size=108384 length=2
05-11 14:30:32.000: I/MemoryCache(4771): cache size=147104 length=3
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/TEST(4771): message here2
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/TEST(4771): message here3
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/TEST(4771): message here4
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/TEST(4771): message here5
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/TEST(4771): message here6
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/TEST(4771): message here7
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/TEST(4771): message here8
05-11 14:30:33.580: D/AndroidRuntime(4771): Shutting down VM
05-11 14:30:33.580: W/dalvikvm(4771): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x55d4fb20)
05-11 14:30:33.580: I/Process(4771): Sending signal. PID: 4771 SIG: 9
05-11 14:30:33.580: D/AndroidRuntime(4771): procName from cmdline: com.fwong.eatright
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.fwong.eatright
05-11 14:30:33.580: D/AndroidRuntime(4771): file written successfully with content: com.fwong.eatright StringBuffer : ;com.fwong.eatright
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771): Process: com.fwong.eatright, PID: 4771
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1034)
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1021)
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:311)
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771):     at com.fwong.eatright.exercise.ListViewAdapter$1.onClick(ListViewAdapter.java:107)
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4443)
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18442)
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
05-11 14:30:33.580: E/AndroidRuntime(4771):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your log messages

Comment: How is it "wrong"? does it not compile? Does it throw exceptions? Is it slow? Please be specific.

Comment: Why don't use setOnItemClickListener of listview instead of creating the whole view's listener in the adapter?

Comment: @ Wai Ha Lee When i select an item form the listview, it auto closes the app.

Comment: @WISHY Do you mean that i should create the onitemclicklistener within the exercisefrag?

Comment: As it said add this line before calling startActivity => intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).

Comment: just tried adding it, but still auto closes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the ApplicationContext to start an Activity. You need to use the ActivityContext for this.

In your exercise fragment where you initialize your adapter change:

```
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), arraylist);
```

To:

```
adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);
```

If that doesn't work, you can also try to set an `OnItemClickListener` on the `ListView` rather than an `OnClickListener` on the `ItemView`. So remove the `OnClickListener` that you have set in the `getView()` method of your adapter. But rather, when you intialize the adapter and set it to the `ListView` also call `ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)` and paste your functionality there. This Listener is used as best practice regarding the handling of the selection of list items.

What happens when you do it your way instead of the way I described here above is that every time a View gets loaded (which is a lot of times since your are using a ListView) the application needs to allocate memory to set an OnClickListener. Now you need to only allocate it once.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! It did help me solve one of the part where the text were greyed out instead of appearing black, however when i select an item from the list, the app still auto closes.

Comment: @JohnW With the same exception as you posted?

Comment: It is not showing the previous exceptions, except for the "message here1" which is before the onclick method.

Comment: @JohnW I've updated my answer, could you try that out?

Comment: Sorry but just to be clear, i will remove the itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() section in the ListViewAdapter and insert the listView.setOnItemClickListener(...) after listView.setAdapter(adapter)?

Comment: @JohnW Exactly. And this handler does the same thing as your old OnClickListener

Comment: i will try it, could you also please check your email, @hotmail? Thank you!

Comment: timkranen@hotmail.com right? i did send a mail from my gmail, about an hour ago

Comment: @JohnW Are you sure you sent the email to that address? I didn't receive anything.

Answer (score 0):

Add setOnItemClickListener in your Fragment to listView

```
listview = (ListView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.listview);
 new DownloadJSON().execute(); 
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             TextView t=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
             Log.e("title",t.getText().toString());
         }
    });
```

Remove this line

```
listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

Remove the listener from your adapter.

Comment: Could you maybe please, show me where do i insert that? and how about the contents of the listener in the adapter?

Comment: after you call new DownloadJSON().execute();  add the listener in onCreateView

Comment: You can get all of your data inside the listener as I showed you example. Just try it once and let me know if you face any issues

Comment: The app auto closed when i selected the ExerciseFragment from the nav drawer list,

Comment: with the new edit, the app does not auto close and in logcat it posts the title of the selected item. what is the next step, and what could your email be, to continue the discussion?

Comment: What else you want to do?

Comment: i need to show the contents of the selected item in the list view,

Comment: I cannot teach whole of the android and coding. You are programmer so start doing it yourself and when you are stuck at something start fighting it to find a solution.

Comment: If my answer has solved your problem would request you to please accept it.